# chgrp to group I am not a member of

Tags: apache-2.2, www-data, chgrp

I'm creating git repositories, ldap accounts and ldap groups using PHP application. Everything works fine, but I have a problem to set right permissions to git repositories. Every ldap user is a member of some ldap group, so I want to change group on git repository (regular directory) to specific ldap group. The problem is, that user `www-data` can't change group to any other he is not member of. How can I change group after creating directory under apache/www-data user?

```
www-data@server:/home/git$ mkdir repo.git
www-data@server:/home/git$ chgrp mygroup repo.git
chgrp: changing group of `repo.git/': Operation not permitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to make `www-data` a member of `mygroup` or use the superuser account to make the change. In either case, you'll need root access or somebody with root access to help you.

Comment: I have a root access on this machine, that's not a problem. Problem is that I can't do it manually, because this repositories and groups are made dynamically via web application, so I even can't  make `www-data` member of `mygroup`, it must be on the fly. Maybe I can set crontab, but isn't there any better solution?

Comment: Could you make `www-data` a member of the group when you're creating it?

Comment: That's not possible because everything is run under `www-data` and I can't assign me to whatever group I want.

Comment: Sounds like a cron job or some kind of event-based triggering (i.e. when a new group appears, do something) is what you need. If you don't need `www-data` to become a member of the new groups immediately, a cron job that adds it seems like the best solution.

Comment: I fnally made it using cronjob. I found something useful e.g. here http://serverfault.com/questions/157272/allow-apache-to-run-a-command-as-a-different-user but I needed really simple solution and now it is already done:)